# Oauth_server authenticates but subsequent requests return "True" with 403 Unauthorized status

Tags: 7, commerce, services, authentication-authorization

I have successfully setup Oauth2 in Drupal 7 and I am able to get token from the `Oauth2/token` endpoint. I need to implement, **Implicit Flow (Client-Side Flow)** as this endpoint will be used by client-side Js application. Though I have turned on the Oauth as authentication provider in Services and also enabled it at the resource settings, I am getting the response as below:

```
[
    true
]
```

However, this endpoints work when authentication is disabled and used anonymously.

[image: Options for getting token in Postman]

The failed request is below:
[image: This fails with 401 Unauthorized.]

Not able to find any further details. I somehow need to use services using Oauth2 as the authentication method.

Comment: Ok this depends on many things, so as this is returning 404 What web services are you accepting?  as you have application/json as a header can you try "/api/system/connect.json" ? what methods are you using GET or POST ? aslo what happens when you hit the url in a browser ?

Comment: @TaggartJensen  Actually it's returning `401, unauthorized`. I think I have accidentally picked wrong screenshot. 

I also tried `/api/system/connect.json`. It still returns `401`. I am using Post method, but I tried with `GET` after reading your comment. In `GEt` its giving `404`. In browser also its showing `404`.

Comment: Anyone with similar issues? :/